# In which case should I use System.in.close()?

Tags: java, opentsdb, system.in

when I am reading the code of opentsdb:

```
try {
    System.in.close();  // Release a FD we don't need.
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Failed to close stdin", e);
}
```

After searching this question on the Internet, I can't find a suitable answer. I don't understand why they write `system.in.close()`, and I want to know if we don't add this code block, what will happen?

Comment: Why do you feel compelled to do this?  I see no good reason.

Comment: The JVM will close `System.in` when the program terminates.

Comment: They seem to just be asking why the library is doing it. They don't seem to show intent to do it themselves.

Comment: One thing to note tough. If you **do** close it, you cannot use the `InputStream` anymore. This could lead to exceptions _somewhere_ else in the application. I would not recommend doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably only if you used [`System.setIn()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) to override the standard input. One normally does not close the standard input, it's handled by JVM process shutdown.